# How do I rebase existing class to remove certain interfaces that it implements

Tags: java, kotlin, byte-buddy

Folks, could you please advise how I can rebase existing class so that it **doesn't** have particular interface in its parents ?

For example

```
interface One {
  fun one(): Unit
}

interface Two {
 fun two(): Unit
}

class Test: One, Two {
  // implementation of one() and two()
}

val newClass = ByteBuddy()
    .rebase(Test::class.java)
    .name("com.test.Test2")
    .implement(Two::class.java)
    .make()
    .load(this.javaClass.classLoader, ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER)
    .loaded

val inst = newClass.declaredConstructors.first().newInstance()
val isOne = inst is One
```

Unfortunately `isOne` is still true. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it through creating delegate class like this

```
val fieldDelegate = "delegate"
val unloaded = ByteBuddy()
    .subclass(Any::class.java)
    .defineField(fieldDelegate, Test::class.java, Opcodes.ACC_PRIVATE or Opcodes.ACC_FINAL)
    .name(Test::class.java.canonicalName + "Wrapper")
    .implement(Two::class.java)
    .defineConstructor(Visibility.PUBLIC)
    .withParameters(Test::class.java)
    .intercept(MethodCall.invoke(Object::class.java.getConstructor()).andThen(FieldAccessor.ofField(fieldDelegate).setsArgumentAt(0)))
    .method(ElementMatchers.isAbstract())
    .intercept(MethodDelegation.toField(fieldDelegate))
    .make()

val clazz = unloaded
    .load(Test::class.java.classLoader, ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER)
    .loaded
```

Answer (score 1):

Byte Buddy does not really aim for removing properties. What you can do is to use ASM via the visit method, to remove elements from the byte code.

Or you can declare a new class, define it the way you and name it the same as the class you wanted to change.